# How to store zipcode in salesforce sales cloud if I've latitude & longitude available?

Tags: geolocation, sales-cloud

We've build an Andoird App which store users location as latitude & longitude at the time of registration. This data is being pushed into salesforce sales cloud. Can I convert this piece of information into zipcode.

Zipcode is easy to understand and my sales team can easily follow up with customers and can provide relevant offerings based on customer's location.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Salesfroce if you have Address, you can automatically get the Latitude and Longitude for that Address using Account, COntact Geocoding. You can read about it [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_dot_com_clean_admin_automatically_get_geocodes_for_addresses.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F&type=5)

What you are looking for is Reverse Geocoding, ie to get Address(Postcode) using geolocation, which is not a feature in salesforce. But as you are in Android App you can convert the geoLocation to human readable address/postcode using Google's Reverse Geolocation API. You can have a look at it

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse